# Dependency Injection for Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unity-container

what is the way to register a Generic class with 3 arguments

```
public interface ITest<T,V,VE>
{

}

public class TestRespository<T,V,VE>:ITest<T,V,VE>
{

}
```

i had registered like this

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ITest<,,>), typeof(ITest<,,>));
```

but unable to get in Constructor as well as

```
service.GetService(typeof(ITest<TestClass, vTestClass, VETestClass>)) as ITest<TestClass, vTestClass, VETestClass>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with call of `AddScoped()` method. You should pass type of implementation in second argument, not the type of interface itself:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ITest<,,>), typeof(TestRespository<,,>));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have changed what you said but its not working.Its coming as Null

Comment: Strange, works fine for me. Could you please update your question with exact copy of your code? Little things matter and now it's unclear where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ITest<,,>), typeof(ITest<,,>));
```

You need to have `implementation` and `interface` not `interface` twice. You are registering `interface` as `interface`, so it cannot be `instantiated`.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ITest<,,>), typeof(TestRepository<,,>));
```

Should do the trick.